# how to pass php variable to website search query using cURL

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

**Question 1**

I want to search a product on website using cURL which should search product by that php variable value and return that product page.

Below is my code for cURL

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.appliancepartspros.com/search.aspx"; 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "q=AP4364034"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close ($ch); 

var_dump($output);

?>
```

Suppose I want to search a `product number = AP4364034` using cURL . How it will return product page.

there are 3 types of search url -

```
http://www.appliancepartspros.com/search.aspx?model=

http://www.appliancepartspros.com/search-alt.aspx?q=

http://www.appliancepartspros.com/search.aspx?p=
```

I am not sure which url return me product page.

**Question 2**

**Using other solution -**

I want to store output url from `anchor tag` to php variable.

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.appliancepartspros.com/search.aspx?p=W10130695"; 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "http://www.appliancepartspros.com/search.aspx?p=W10130695"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$output = curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close ($ch); 

var_dump($output);
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: add it to the url, its not  post

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you.. can u please explain